# Реализован ли в .NET поиск по отсортированным массивам?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли информация о работе C# с коллекциями массивами и тд в плане реализации? Ну, то есть поиск по сортированному массиву примерно в 2 раза быстрее, чем по несортированному. А как происходит поиск в Array, List, Dictionary и тд?

Для примера вот задачка. Есть класс аэропорт(название, координаты). Есть класс коллекция аэропортов. В коллекции есть `List<аэропорт>`, как хранилище объектов аэропорт. В коллекции не может быть 2 аэропорта с одинаковым названием или с одинаковыми координатами. Что быстрее, использовать list.Find(predicate) или добавить к классу коллекции два словаря:

`Dictionary<строка, аэропорт>`

`Dictionary<координаты, аэропорт>`

и искать совпадения по этим коллекциям? Если со словарями поиск будет быстрее, то на сколько?

Comment: Я бы использовал подходящую структуру данных: в `Dictionary` поиск по ключу O(1).

Comment: Насколько именно быстрее, зависит от миллиарда факторов: пропускная способность памяти, производительность процессора, размер ваших данных и размер кэша, скорость сравнения, наличие кастомного компаратора и всё такое. Не ленитесь, сравните скорости сами на **ваших** данных.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В .NET 4.5 и выше есть метод [`List(T).BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx), который использует [алгоритм двоичного поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA). Двоичный поиск намного быстрее, чем простой итеративный поиск.

Вот пример:

```
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 56, 112 };
ints.BinarySearch(1);   // 0
ints.BinarySearch(56);  // 1
ints.BinarySearch(112); // 2
ints.BinarySearch(0);   // -1
ints.BinarySearch(10);  // -2
ints.BinarySearch(100); // -3
ints.BinarySearch(200); // -4
```

Для `List<аэропорт>`, в принципе это тоже возможно, но надо создать `IComparer` для аэропортов.

> Что быстрее, использовать list.Find(predicate) или добавить к классу коллекции два словаря?

Для больших коллекцией быстрее использовать словари.

Согласно документации, [временная сложность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0) [метода `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ru/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) приближается `O(1)`. Временная сложность метода `List.BinarySearch` - `O(log(n))`, и временная сложность метода `List.Find` - `O(n)`.

Comment: Спасибо. Добавлю лишь, что `List<T>.BinarySearch` присутствует в .NET с версии 2, но там он не был перегружаемым.

Comment: @iRumba О, спасибо, я это не заметил

Answer (score 4):

1. Описание поиска в отсортированном быстрее чем в неотсортированно обсуждается тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array
2. Поиск в `Array` и `List` происходит простым циклом и сравниванием членов массива\списка.
3. Поиск в `Dictionary` происходит через хэш таблицу.

У `List` есть метод `BinarySearch`, он ищет бинарным поиском но только в отсортированном массиве, то что массив отсортирован вы должны гарантировать самостоятельно.

Для примера с аэропортами лучше использовать `Dictionary`. Но в данном случае не совсем понятно какого вида координаты если это числа с плавающей точной то там есть округление, например `(1.0 / 3.0)` не равно `(1.1 / 3.3)`

Поиск в Listе требует итерирования всего списка.
Поиск в Dictionary не требует итерирования коллекции и работает в среднем за 1 операцию.

Answer (score 2):

Архитектура современного железа такова, что доступ к кэш-памяти во много раз быстрее, чем к основной памяти. Поэтому в критически-важных по времени алгоритмах следует учитывать эту разницу.

Существует особый класс алгоритмов и структур данных, [осведомлённых о кэше](http://www.1024cores.net/home/in-russian/ram---ne-ram-ili-cache-conscious-data-structures). Смотрите разделы Cache-Conscious Binary Search и Hot/Cold Data Splitting. Их применение на действительно больших объёмах данных может быть существенно выгодней.

Comment: а вы знаете как это (*Cache-Conscious Binary Search*) делается на c# ?

Comment: @4per - практически я такое не делал, лишь теорию изучал. Раньше, когда я познакомился с этими вещами, в сети находилось много документов (pdf) с теорией такого поиска и таких структур. На удивление, сейчас сходу нагуглилось что-то реально [реализованное](https://aakinshin.net/ru/posts/cache-conscious-binary-search/).

Answer (score 0):

В .NET поиск по неотсортированным структурам (те же List, Dictionary, T[]) происходит простым перебором элементов в цикле (да, в Dictionary тоже происходит перебор ключей).

Для списка это выглядит примерно так:

```
// разумеется, реальный метод должен 
// быть несколько сложнее за счет проверок
// аргументов и прочей логики
public T Find(Predicate<T> pred) 
{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < data.Length; i++) 
    {
        if(pred(data[i])) 
        {
            return data[i];
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

для словарей это будет выглядеть похожим образом с тем отличием, что вместо метода Find и предиката там используется индексатор с обращением по ключу, соответственно, при поиске будет использоваться не вызов предиката, а сравнение хэш-кодов ключа и перебираемых ключей. Скорее всего сравнение хэшкодов будет происходить быстрее, особенно если предикат имеет какую-то сложную логику (не стоит также забывать, что лямбда-выражение предиката разворачивается в анонимный класс, который также требует создание экземпляра и выделение под него памяти). Но утверждать это на 146% я бы не стал. Если вам действительно важна скорость поиска, то я бы на вашем месте вначале провел тесты для сравнения того и другого вариантов. но, думаю, поиск по словарю будет все же побыстрее

Comment: поиск в словаре по ключу всегда выполняется за время O(1), если хеш-фунцкия хорошая. Не надо пугать новичков.

Comment: @PavelMayorov посмотрите исходники Dictionary<T,U> из .NET. Там поиск выполняется именно перебором всей коллекции ключей со сравнением хешей ключей. Сильно сомневаюсь, что цикл for имеет сложность O(1)

Comment: И в чем проблема-то? В каждой корзине O(1) элементов. Поиск перебирает все элементы одной корзины, а потому работает за время O(1).

Comment: @PavelMayorov действительно, что-то я затупил

Comment: @PavelMayorov а что значит О(1)? ))

Comment: В данном случае это означает, что время не зависит от числа элементов в словаре. Подробнее - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/«O»_большое_и_«o»_малое